# C input checking and previous output validation code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, io

I have this following piece of code to check an input against a dictionary of common words and also check if input matches previous input stored in the passHistory file.My problem is that the strcmp method to compare strings in C doesn't seem to execute correctly in my code as it fails to show appropriate error if common word used or input was already used in passHistory.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 30
#define gC_FOUND 99
#define gC_NOT_FOUND -99


int checkWordInFile(char * fileName,char * theWord);



int main()
{

    char userString[MAX + 1];

    int iResult;

    printf("Enter your string: ");
    gets(userString);


    printf("\n\nYou entered: %s, please wait, checking in dictionary.\n\n", userString);
    iResult = checkWordInFile("dictionary.txt",userString);




    if( iResult == gC_FOUND )
    {
        printf("\nFound your word in the dictionary");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nCould not find your word in the dictionary");
    }

    iResult = checkWordInFile("passHistory.txt",userString);
    if( iResult == gC_FOUND )
    {
        printf("\nPassword used");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nOk to use!");
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");

} /* end of main */

int checkWordInFile(char * fileName,char * theWord){

    FILE * fptr;
    char fileString[MAX + 1];
    int iFound = -99;
    //open the file
    fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNo dictionary file\n");
        printf("\n\n\n");
        system("pause");
        return (0); // just exit the program
    }

    /* read the contents of the file */
    while( fgets(fileString, MAX, fptr) )
    {
        if( 0 == strcmp(theWord, fileString) )
        {
            iFound = -99;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return(0);



}//end of checkwORDiNFile
```

Comment: How do you know that the `strcmp` method isn't working right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) writes the new-line character, if encountered, into the buffer it is populating. Remove it before using `strcmp()`:

```
char* new_line = strrchr(fileString, '\n');
if (new_line) *new_line = 0;
```

Note that [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) is a dangerous api due to no bounds checking on the input, potentially resulting in a buffer overrun. A safer mechanism for reading the user input would be `fgets()` or [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with the `%Ns` specifier where `N` specifies the maximum number of characters to read, and `N` must be one less than the size of the array to allow for the null terminator:

```
scanf("%30s", userString);
```

When the string is found in the file there is no reason to keep searching the remainder of the file, `break` from the `while` to avoid unnecessary processing. Note that `iFound`s value never changes within the `checkWordInFile()` and is not used as the return value: `0` is always returned. I think you meant `iFound =  gC_FOUND;` within the loop. You have also defined macros to indicate found and not found but do not use these within the function, but use the hard-coded values.

Comment: Hi hmjd,thanks for the tips and teaching me a lesson at the same time,will be usefull for future use :)